# Compare two models using Anova in SAS

Tags: r, sas, anova, model-comparison

Is there a way in SAS to compare two regression models using ANOVA. What i want to replicate is -  in R if i have 2 models - model1 & model2 i can directly run `anova(model1, model2)` to find if there is a significant difference between the two.

Is there a way to do the same in SAS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because SAS doesn't store models that way. However, you can run each model (in PROC GLM or whatever) and then compare the results. You can get some of this by looking at the different "types" of error, too.

Comment: Thanks. Guess it would be easier if SAS does incorporate some of the features available in R in the next version.

Comment: Adding a feature like this would be a radical change for SAS. It would probably require a whole redesign.  I don't see it happening. R is (at least somewhat) object oriented.  SAS is not.